# Find a weighted Sobolev space $X\subset L^1(\mathbb R^n)$ such that, if $u\in X$ and has zero mean, then $u$ is in the Hardy space $\mathcal H^1$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, hardy-spaces

I have asked nearly the same [question on Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455725/if-f-is-bounded-decays-fast-enough-at-infinity-and-int-f-0-does-this-impl), but it is maybe too low level.

Let $\mathcal H^1(\mathbb R^n)$ be the real Hardy space (as in [Stein's book](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt1bpmb3s), Chapter 3). It is well known that $\mathcal H^1(\mathbb R^n)\subset L^1(\mathbb R^n)$ and all its elements have zero mean.

I am looking for a (possibly sharp) Banach space $X$ of the following form:
$$ \|u\|_{X}=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k} \|(1+|x|)^N\partial^\alpha u\|_{L^p}, $$
$p\in[1,\infty]$, such that a function $u\in X$ belongs to $\mathcal H^1(\mathbb R^n)$ if and only if $\int_{\mathbb R^n} f=0$.

If polynomial weights are not sufficient, then it would be fine to have exponential weights, etc... A related question: is any Schwartz function with zero mean also in $\mathcal H^1(\mathbb R^n)$?

I wonder whether one can take $X=W^{k,1}(\mathbb R^n)$ for $k$ large enough, that is, $p=1$ and $N=0$.

---

What I know is that any function in $L^q(\mathbb R^n)$, $q>1$ with compact support and zero mean belongs to $\mathcal H^1(\mathbb R^n)$ (and the $L^q$ assumption can be relaxed to $L\log L$). I had a quick look at Stein's book and Grafakos' book, but I did not find anything like what I am looking for.

I have the suspect that assuming only decay of $u$ of any kind ($k=0$) is not sufficient, and one needs also the decay of some of its derivatives, but I could be wrong. That would be an answer for the question on MO.

---

**Edit.** It is clear that the main problem is at low frequencies. A weighted $L^p$ bound on $u$ would ensure that the Fourier transform is bounded and regular close to $\xi=0$. I am looking for spaces that have no other conditions on the low frequencies of $u$, this is why I am requiring $X$ to be a weighted Sobolev spaces.

Comment: Depends on how flexible is your notion of "nice" Banach spaces. But the homogeneous Besov space $\dot{\mathrm{B}}^0_{1,1}$ does the job. While still being of Sobolev regularity "0".

Comment: More generally, one can identify the Hardy space $\mathcal{H}^1$ with the ***homogeneous*** Triebel-Lizorkin space $\dot{\mathrm{F}}^{0}_{1,2}$. Maybe you will have more results looking at it that way.

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for a Banach space like the one in the question, basically a weighted Soblev space. I don't want any sort of strong condition on the low frequencies of $u$ (besides boundedness and regularity of the Fourier transform, which would follow from the weighted estimates), so, Besov and T-L scales are not what I am looking for. Maybe I should change the title

Comment: Thank you for your last remark!

Comment: Schwartz functions for which the support of the Fourier transform is away from 0, embeds continuously in the Hardy space $\mathcal{H}^1$. This is an exercise one can find in several harmonic analysis book. By Sobolev embeddings, you should obtain that the closure of this Schwartz (sub)space with respect to a sufficiently high $\mathrm{W}^{k,1}$ norm should embed countinously. Notice that support assumption on the Fourier transform guarantees the $0$-mean property. Is this closer to what you are looking for ?

Comment: I agree with the first statement of course, but I don’t see how to use Sobolev embeddings to show that $\mathcal H^1$ contains the subspace of functions in $W^{k,1}$ with mean zero. Can I ask you to add more details?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148899/discussion-between-lorenzo-pompili-and-togle).